# converting prepared statement - Oracle to SQL server

Tags: java, sql-server, oracle, migration

Trying to convert Oracle queries to Sql Server, and I have this code:

```
PreparedStatement ps=conn.prepareStatement("update Test set name=:1, age=:2 where name=:3 ");

ps.setString(1,"joe"); 
ps.setString(2,"25");
ps.setString(3,"may");
```

In the above prepared statement, is there a sql server equivalent to `:1` (other than `?`).

When I run the same query in Sql Server I get this error:

> The index 1 is out of range.

Comment: `Update Test Set Name = @Name, Age = @Age Where Name = @SomeOtherName`

Comment: What is your client language?

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn: java